# class type as variable and use it in constructor in c++

Tags: c++

```
class c1{
public:
    c1(int AO, int AE){
        x=AO;
        y=AE;
    }

private:
    int x,y;
};


class c2{
public:


//c2(int x, int y, bool target): obj1(x, y), flag(target){}


c2(int x, int y, bool target){
  obj1=c1(x,y)
  flag=target;
}

private:
    c1 obj1;
    bool flag;
};
```

If i write the line with the constructor in the comments, it runs. How can i write c2(int x, int y, bool target) in order to compile? (the error message is not matching function for call to 'c1:c1()')

Comment: Use the member initializer list in the `c2` constructor to initialize `obj1`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor.)

Comment: You missed a `;` at the end of `obj1=c1(x,y)`.

Comment: There is probably nothing in C++ that has a higher ratio of usefulness to time spent teaching it than the Member Initializer List.

Answer (score 1):

```
c2(int x, int y, bool target): obj1(x, y), flag(target){}
```

When this starts executing, uses the `:` calls to determine how to construct each member. This uses the `object1(x,y)` constructor, then the `flag(target)` constructor, then calls the body, which is empty.  This makes sense.

```
c2(int x, int y, bool target){
  obj1=c1(x,y)
  flag=target;
}
```

When this starts executing, it uses the `:` calls to determine how to construct each member. Since this is empty, it uses the default constructor for `obj1` and `flag`, and then wants to calls the body.  But the initial constructor obviously can't compile, because `obj1` has no default constructor! `no matching function for call to 'c1:c1()'`